# Show price including VAT in registered customer's shopping cart in Admin page

Tags: php

I have set 20% VAT with catalog prices -> Including VAT and Shipping Prices-> Including VAT and VAT is working fine. In Admin side, Customers->Manage Customers->Shopping Cart Tab, the price and total shows excluding VAT. I want to show the price and total including VAT. In all other areas price is shown correct except in admin shopping cart. Please help. I have attached some screenshots. In the admin shopping cart it shows, 104.17 instead of 125. I need to show 125 there.
[image: VAT Settings][image: Shopping Cart Admin]

Comment: In Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View/Cart.php I found the header of shopping cart. Can anyone tell, where did the price of product come from.